# Component keep-out on particular layer in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I'm making a heat sink footprint for TO220 in Altium. I think route tracks under the heat sink is not a good idea. So I want to give the footprint a keep-out, but the keep-out region on Keep-Out layer applied to both top and bottom layer, though my heat sink sits on the top layer. So any methods to add a keep-out region only applied to the layer where the footprint sit on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a region on top layer and check the Keepout checkbox:

[image: Region]

The traces on other layers are not affected:

[image]

Comment: Does this method actually add the copper that is shown above?

Comment: @TomBrendlinger No, it does not.